# How to Iterate through a list and create/save variables

Tags: python, list

If I have a list

```
subjects = ['Tests', 'Assignments', 'Quizzes']
for i in subjects:
    i = raw_input("What percentage do {} make up your grade \n".format(i))
```

I know this code doesn't work (I tried), but how would I 1) iterate through a list 2) create a variable and 3) save data to that variable

In the end I want so I can use them to calculate further data

```
tests = x%
assignments = x%
quizzes = x%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer suggested by thefourtheye can solve your problem but it does not really scale. Suppose you now have 20 subjects instead of 3, now you have to manually make 20 variables:

```
A, B, C, D, ... = [float(raw_input(formatter(i))) for i in subjects]
```

Using a map instead is definitely the way to go. No need to create one variable for each subject string:

```
score_map = {'Tests' : 0, 'Assignments' : 0, 'Quizzes' : 0}
for subject in score_map:
    score_map[subject] = float(raw_input("What percentage do {} make up your grade \n".format(subject)))
# Now you can access each score
for subject in score_map:
    print "{0} makes up {1} percent".format(subject, score_map[subject])
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't always know what the subjects lists could be. For example it could be only 'Tests' and 'Assignments'. How would I calculate for that?

Comment: Use function then. Pass the list in, construct a score_map using the for loop (initialize value of each subject to be 0), the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use List comprehension and variable unpacking techniques here, like this

```
subjects = ['Tests', 'Assignments', 'Quizzes']
format_str = "What percentage do {} make up your grade \n"
tests, assignments, quizzes = [raw_input(format_str.format(i)) for i in subjects]
```

This will get data for each of the category and prepare a list and as we know that it will have only three elements, we can conveniently unpack the values to three variables on the left side.

By default, `raw_input` will return String, if you want to convert the user inputs to numbers, you can convert them like this

```
formatter = "What percentage do {} make up your grade \n".format
tests, assignments, quizzes = [float(raw_input(formatter(i))) for i in subjects]
```